# AngularJS : rootScope object auto save

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently work on a kind of HTML previewer.
I'm developping a new feature to auto save recents modifications.

I got a function that returns an object with the data I want to save

```
var saveSkin = function(){
 var saveObj = {
    "name" : $rootScope.skin.name,
  "type": $rootScope.type,
   "skin" : {
     "name" : $rootScope.skin.name,
     "td" : $rootScope.skin.td,
     "client" : $rootScope.skin.client,
     "aid" : $rootScope.skin.aid
   },
   "skinSettings" : {
     "bgUrl" : $rootScope.skinSettings.bgUrl,
     "bgColor" : $rootScope.skinSettings.bgColor,
     "bannerHeight" : $rootScope.skinSettings.bannerHeight
   },
   "components" : $rootScope.components,
   "exportCss" : $rootScope.exportCss,
   "exportJs" : $rootScope.exportJs
 };
 return saveObj;
};
```

And another function (shorten here) that saves this object into another object each X seconds.

```
var autoSave = function(){
 $interval(function(){
   creativeSave.push(saveSkin());
 }, 3000);
};
```

The problem is that all the objects inside the parent object have the same value, like if each object is auto-updating with rootScope value, while I want them to keep rootScope of the moment where they were created.

I would really appreciate if you had any idea of how to fix this.
Thanks, Adrien

Comment: Sorry i'm not clear what happens and what you want to happen. Currently all the objects you add are the same, meaning they don't get updated when you change the `$rootScope`?

Comment: @AlexD He means he wants to instantiate an object with the values of $rootScope at a given time and keep them that way until he changes it. What's happening now is that even if he doesn't call the saveSkin() function, the object gets updated automatically whenever the $rootScope values change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object changes without you calling `saveSkin()` probably because not all properties you use there are `value type`, some of them are pointers to objects.

So you have 2 choices as far as I can see:

1) Save only value types in the `saveObj`

2) Clone the object each time you update it, the easiest way to do it is (not very efficient)

```
$scope.savedObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(saveObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
var saveSkin = function (skin, type, skinSettings, components, exportCss, exportJs) {
    return {
        "name": skin.name,
        "type": type,
        "skin": {
            "name": skin.name,
            "td": skin.td,
            "client": skin.client,
            "aid": skin.aid
        },
        "skinSettings": {
            "bgUrl": skinSettings.bgUrl,
            "bgColor": skinSettings.bgColor,
            "bannerHeight": skinSettings.bannerHeight
        },
        "components": components,
        "exportCss": exportCss,
        "exportJs": exportJs
    };
};
```

And than call it like this:

```
var autoSave = function () {
    $interval(function () {
        creativeSave.push(saveSkin($rootScope.skin, $rootScope.type, $rootScope.skinSettings, $rootScope.components, $rootScope.exportCss, $rootScope.exportJs));
    }, 3000);
};
```

Maybe then it's even possible to change `$rootScope` to `$scope`

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly understand what you want but , may be this will help you. here when we use $rootScope.$watch like this it will get execute on every rootScope change .

```
    $rootScope.$watch(function(data){
         creativeSave.push(saveSkin());
    });
```